# How to generate a scatter plot in Julia, with colors of the points defined by a third variable?

Tags: plot, julia

Let's say, I have points whose coordinates are (x,y), and I want their color to be defined by w.

```
using Plots

x = rand(10)
y = rand(10)
w = rand(10)
```

In MATLAB, I can generate what I want with `scatter(x,y,[],w,"filled")`. Is there a similar function in Julia?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `scatter(x, y, zcolor = w)`.

You can additionally set the size of the marker in the following way.

```
scatter(x, y, zcolor = w, markersize = 10)
```